# Possible to start Voom outliner from modeline?

Tags: neovim, plugin, modeline

I use the Voom outliner and would like to start it automatically for certain files  using the modeline  feature.

I tried as first line in the file:
// vim: Voom asciidoc

But when is start it:
Unknown option: Voom

Any clues what might be the problem?
Or is this not possible?

Br,
Martin

Comment: Try `:help modeline`; you can only set(local) options, not run arbitrary commands. Use `:help autocommand` to automatically run commands for events, or filetype plugins when the command should be run when the filetype is detected.